# Get ID value from set of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I'm trying to get the **id** of the set of radio buttons. Here is the HTML for it.

```
<input id="1" type="radio" title="2" value="6/1/2010" name="vacationDay">
<input id="2" type="radio" title="2" value="6/2/2010" name="vacationDay">
<input id="3" type="radio" title="2" value="6/3/2010" name="vacationDay" checked='checked'>
```

Here is my Javascript.

```
var updateDay = $('input[name=vacationDay]:checked').val();
```

It returns the value (6/3/2010) of the selected radio button . I would like to get the id of the checked button (3) as well.
Ideas?

Comment: Thank you to everyone that replied, all responses worked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var $radio = $('input[name=vacationDay]:checked');
var updateDay = $radio.val();
var id = $radio.attr('id');
```

[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 6):

```
   var btnId = $('input[name=vacationDay]:checked').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 3):

not sure if this is what you wish for :

```
var id = $('input[name=vacationDay]:checked').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your `.val()` to `.attr('id')`!

```
var updateDay = $('input[name=vacationDay]:checked').attr('id');​
```

Answer (score 0):

try

> var updateDay = $('input[name=vacationDay]:checked').attr('id')